# how to draw alphabets and draw line on it by finger?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to create letters and words dynamically on view and also I want to draw line on it by finger.

For example I have letters like A as given in picture:

[image]

I would like to draw like this as given in picture:

[image]

The problem is that the line is drawn on the whole view. I want to find points contain letters and only draw line on letters contain points. if any idea or suggestion then let me know.

Comment: The best way would be to look out for some existing libraries that have this capability. If none exists, then Vector Imaging should be the way ahead. You can have vector representation of all 26 alphabets,initially.  Then as the user draws, you will need to convert that motion into vector Image. Finally you can compare the user's input vector drawing to the set of 26 standard alphabets, and have an algorithm that picks up the best match.

Comment: It's quite a broad question. If you want a ready to use solution, I'd first look into existing handwriting recognition libraries - this is not a problem that's trivial.

Comment: I think this library might help you https://github.com/McoyJiang/TracingSample

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my problem by using two images one is a normal image of an "A" and other is transparent image of an "A", in between these two images I add the custom view on which I draw freehand line.

Using below code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DrawingView dv ;   
    private Paint mPaint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout mtile=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mtile);
        dv = new DrawingView(this);
        mtile.addView(dv);
        RelativeLayout rvtrans=new RelativeLayout(this);
        rvtrans.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.at);
        mtile.addView(rvtrans);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);  
    }

    public class DrawingView extends View {

        public int width;
        public  int height;
        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        Context context;
        private Paint circlePaint;
        private Path circlePath;

        public DrawingView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            context=c;
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);  
            circlePaint = new Paint();
            circlePath = new Path();
            circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
            circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
            Log.d("start xy==>", x+","+y);
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            Log.d("move xy==>", x+","+y);
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if ((dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            /*  circlePath.reset();
                circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);*/
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            Log.d("end xy", mX+","+mY);
            circlePath.reset();
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
                }
                return true;
        }  
    }
}
```

and activity_main.xml is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mtile"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/a"
>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hey i use your code its reallly amazing but i want to do that when user complete the whole letter "A" then want to open one dialog box that shows "completed the Letter"A".how can i do that?? If u know please tell me....!!!

Comment: Would you be able to provide the source code for this, for some reason it's not working for me. @Richard Tingle.

Comment: @blazing I'm not the author of this post just an editor of it. It's bhavikkumar's answer

Comment: Would you be able to provide the source code for this, for some reason it's not working for me. @ bhavikkumar

Comment: Hey would you happen to have the source code @bhumika rijiya